# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.experimental' has no attribute 'export_saved_model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

can anyone here help me fix this? i cant find the solution to this in the internet. also i am not good in python/machine learning

````
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, SHOE_SAVED_MODEL)
shoe_model = tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model(SHOE_SAVED_MODEL,
custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})



AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-82a8de315a24> in <module>()
      2 
      3 SHOE_SAVED_MODEL = "saved_models/shoe"
----> 4 tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, SHOE_SAVED_MODEL)
      5 shoe_model = tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model(SHOE_SAVED_MODEL,
      6 custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})

AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.experimental' has no attribute 'export_saved_model'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Which TensorFlow you are using? For 2.9.1, there's not `tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model`, but you can use this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/experimental/export_saved_model.

This type of question you can easily look at the documentation. Python libraries are changing all the time, especially the experimental ones.

Comment: hello can i just share the notebook to you?